# How to classify with Markov models

Tags: classification, cross-validation, markov-process

I am reading a paper about attribution modeling [Three Essays based on Clickstream Data:
Analyzing, Understanding and Managing
Online Customer Behavior](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/view/eth:48854) which talks about a way to calculate attribution using Markov models. An executive summary can be found [here](http://wcai.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AD_P2_Schumann_Anderl_Wangenheim_Becker.pdf).

The authors say they conducted an evaluation of the method by doing a 10-fold cross-validation. However I am still not sure how they did it. I assume that they used the inferred Markov model to predict the next state based on the previous nth states depending on the order of the model.
In that case I guess they try to predict if a user is going to convert or not based on her previous nth history.

Is my interpretation right?